# How to log page generation time and number of MySQL queries for Silverstripe

Tags: php, mysql, logging, silverstripe

We are working on a large Silverstripe website which has a large database (700,000+ rows on one table). There are issues with hosting performance which are hard to quantify so I'm looking for ways of measuring the page generation time and how many SQL queries are being used to generate each page.

For a past SS project I hacked the core code to record the pageload time in milliseconds, counting the number of SQL queries, and write to a CSV file.

However I'd really like to avoid changing the core code and was wondering if there are other options/ modules out there that do a similar thing.

Ideally I'd like a CSV which looks something like this

`Timestamp,           URL,                         milliseconds,  queries
2016/11/10 14:10:00, http://www.example.com/url1,          345,       67
2016/11/10 14:10:05, http://www.example.com/url2,          123,       45`

Comment: I recommend xdebug profiler, it is very handy and does exactly what you need. https://xdebug.org/docs/profiler . To read the output , you might need desktop programs depending on your OS.

Comment: There is also a debug toolbar for SilverStripe, see https://github.com/lekoala/silverstripe-debugbar. We also mentioned it in our talk at the last StripeConEU, slides are at https://speakerdeck.com/wernerkrauss/debug-silverstripe-like-a-pro

Comment: @wmk - if you'd like to post an answer about the debug bar I'd happily accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also a [debug toolbar for SilverStripe](http://github.com/lekoala/silverstripe-debugbar), we also mentioned it in our [talk about debugging SilverStripe](https://speakerdeck.com/wernerkrauss/debug-silverstripe-like-a-pro) at the last StripeConEU.

You can install it to your require-dev section using composer:

```
composer require --dev lekoala/silverstripe-debugbar
```

and of course flush after installation.

Then you see a small SilverStripe logo at the bottom left which hides the actual debug bar:

[image: Screenshot of SilverStripe Debugbar in action]

With this you can (beside much useful information) display all queries and also filter for duplicate queries only.